# Using multiple submit buttons in one form with a tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using submit button with a tag. However, one more button needs to be used.
Can I use two submit buttons with a tag in one form?

```
<div>
    ...
    <form id="action-1" action='my action1 html' method="post">
        <input class="mini-action" type="text" name="mini" value="1">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="details">
    // A tag submit button currently in use
    <a title="action1" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('action-1').submit()">action-1</a>
</div>

<div class="details">
    // ToDo: Here I want to send to action2 url when submit button is clicked.
    <a title="action2" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('action-2').submit()">action-2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The tags you are showing are not submit buttons.
But yes you can it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags you used are not submit buttons but links hijacked to act as buttons, additionally it is considered to be best practice to place the submit buttons *inside* the form they submit.

You can override the submit button's action with the attribute `formaction`

```html
<form action="action-1">
  <!-- input fields go here -->
  <button type="submit">this will trigger action-1</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="action-2">this will trigger action-2</button>
</form>
```